# Find the greatest common divisor of $119 121$ and $2 866 980$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Find the greatest common divisor of $119 121$ and $2 866 980$.

This was to be solved in 30 seconds. I thought of using the Euclidean Algo approach but seems too slow for this.

Is it the desired (and the fastest) approach?

Comment: $2019$.  Yes... the Euclidean Algorithm seems to be the fastest.  But no calculator??

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm takes three steps, so it's not that bad. You could first divide by (the obvious) $3$, though I don't know that it helps much.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, no calculator. and if I remember correctly this was to be solved mentally (will verify, haven't asked the organizers yet).

Comment: @MathsWhiz, You may use direct division and remainder will be $8076=4\times 2019$. The greatest common divisor exists in remainder.

Comment: Who invents such exercises ?

Comment: I'd have won.  My first thought was "I bet it's the current year."  Less than one second.  And this points to my issue with the "math contest" cults.  They have their place, but at some point, young people can be distracted down that path, when they'd be better off studying real math.